# Java Exercise Solving Problem - Control Structures

Tags: java

Acquire the grades of pupils in a class from the keyboard by storing the data in a vector. The number N of students must be entered from the keyboard. Validation of the number of students (n between 1 and 35) and of the marks entered (grade between 1 and 10) is required

PROBLEM : When I enter a wrong grade, it gives me the opportunity to re-enter the correct value. But if I re-enter the wrong value, it won't give me the option to enter the correct value again. In other words, he has to give me the option to re-enter the value until I type the wrong vote

```java
package es;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class es2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
        int alunni[] = new int[35];
        int valore_voto = 0;
        int somma_voti = 0;
        int numero_voti = 0;
        float media = 0;
    
        System.out.println("Inserisci numero voti");
        numero_voti = tastiera.nextInt();
    
        int i;
    
        for (i = 0; i < numero_voti; i++) {
            System.out.println("Inserisci valore voto");
            valore_voto = tastiera.nextInt();
    
            if (valore_voto >= 1 && valore_voto <= 10) {
                alunni[i] = valore_voto;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Inserisci voto corretto");
                while (valore_voto <= 1 && valore_voto >= 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (valore_voto<=1 && valore_voto >=10);` is a loop without a body. Highly unlikely you intended to do that

Comment: You have a `while` loop here with an empty body: `while (valore_voto<=1 && valore_voto >=10);` This is just going to run around forever. You need to add a body to this loop in which the user can enter a new value.

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop:

```
        for (i = 0; i < numero_voti; i++) {
            System.out.println("Inserisci valore voto");
            valore_voto = tastiera.nextInt();
    
            // this cycle would be ommited if valore_voto is in right range
            while(valore_voto < 1 || valore_voto > 10) {
                System.out.printlnt("Inserisci voto corretto");
                //re-enter now:
                valore_voto = tastiera.nextInt();
            }
            alunni[i] = valore_voto;

        }
```

Comment: @Maurizio-Generosi If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.